# Execution of internal loop - Error 'Type Mismatch'

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

I'm writing a macro for the first time and I have a problem with one of my Subs.

When it runs the first time when ROW = 3 it does the internal loop for the Col = 3 to Col = x-2 without any problem. However when ROW increase to 4 I get an Error on the first run of the internal Col loop (Col = 3).

The Error says Run-time error '13' and  Type mismatch, however I don't understand why it would run thru ok on first execution of the loop when ROW = 3 but fail when ROW = 4.

```
For Row = 3 To y - 1

Col = 0
OutputCol = OutputCol + 1

    For Col = 3 To x - 2

    Cells(Col + 3, OutputCol).Value = "L" + Cells(5, Col + 1).Value + "C" + Cells(6, Row).Value + "  " + "EXEC TRANEXEC, " + Line + Cells(5, Col + 1).Value + "," + Company + Cells(6, Row).Value

    Next Col

Next Row
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Marty

Comment: You're concatenating a `String`, so use the concatenation operator `&` instead of `+`.

Comment: You should also avoid using `Row` as a variable in Excel VBA - it hides the internal `Row` member.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Comintern - I updated that, still get the error. Is there any way to get a better understanding of what the error means and what field/s it relates to?

Comment: Yep. They're the same as [the VB6 ones](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264975(v=VS.60).aspx) for the most part.

Answer (score 3):

`Value` is not necessarily a string.  And @Comintern is right - don't redefine `Row`.  Assuming you change `Row` to `RowNum`, try this in your loop:

```
Cells(Col + 3, OutputCol).Value = "L" & CStr(Cells(5, Col + 1).Value) & _
    "C" & CStr(Cells(6, RowNum).Value) & "  " & _
    "EXEC TRANEXEC, " & Line & CStr(Cells(5, Col + 1).Value) & "," & _
    Company & CStr(Cells(6, RowNum).Value)
```

The `CStr()` calls make sure that you get a string representation of `Value`, so that the string-concatenation operator `&` will always have strings to work with.

### Edit

As @Mat's Mug noted, before the code snippet you included, you should be doing something like:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
set ws = ActiveSheet
```

(or whatever worksheet you want instead of `ActiveSheet`).  Then every call to `Cells` should be to `ws.Cells` instead.  That way you will always know which worksheet you are referring to, and you won't have weird errors that depend on factors beyond your control.

Similarly, instead of `ActiveWorkbook`, do `Dim wb as Workbook` and use, e.g., `wb.Sheets`.

Comment: Super CXW - that has resolved it - awesome help. Thanks

Comment: @Mat'sMug great point --- will update momentarily.  Rubberduck looks awesome --- I haven't had time to try it yet, but it is on my list!  I have two 10kloc Word VBA code bases under active development, so the more tool support, the better!

Comment: @MartinSpence glad to hear it!  Would you please hit the checkmark so the system (and future readers) will know at a glance this answer solved your problem?  (Plus, we both get reputation points when you do so :) .)  Welcome to the site --- check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more tips.